# Which one if better than for setting HTML tag to PHP variable's value and initial director to view?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to declared html tag as string value into a **PHP** variable and return that variable in `Nav()` function, which this function will places on MY_Model than I will transfer this value into **$menu** variable on **Pages_Controller**
like 
`$this->data['munu'] = $this->MY_Model("nav");` than I will echo this $menu variable to view as `<?PHP echo $menu; ?>`. So I mean that I will not plane or wrapping my html tag on view I've wrapped it at **Nav()** Function.

So I want to ask all friend it is faster or better than to wrapping $menu variable on html tag in some **files** in **View** folder or not?

**Here is My simple code.**

```
Class Pages extends CI_Controller{
       $this->load->model("MY_Model");
       $this->data['menu'] = $this->MY_Model->nav();
}
```

**Here is My MY_Model**

```
Class MY_Model extends CI_Model{
      Public function nav(){
             $str ='<html><div><nav>Here is the wraper of html tage and PHP variable which retrieve value from Database </nav></div></html>';
return $str;
}
}
```

**Here is My **page.PHP** in view**

```
<?PHP echo $menu; ?>
```

Not Here is just simple code but My code in my website it is properly working as normal but I concern this structures is better than to wrapping **PHP** variable on **HTML tag** at **page.php** or not or it is as the same thing?

Please help to show some idea.

Comment: I would have done the strict minimum in my model (query + return), send the result to my view from the controller (eventually rework it a bit) and build my html tag in my view.

Comment: Yes I'm currently build some website by using this technic but I want to change it because I want to make a pretty clean HTML code on my view by just pass only php variable. But I concern it is faster or not good technic or what.
Sorry what do you mean *strict minimum* ?it will strict us right?

Comment: What I mean by "strict minimum" is that I never rework my data inside my models. Models are only meant to execute queries and return results. Everything else goes to the controller.
Also, you technique isn't wrong or slower it's not very "MVC friendly". Your html will not be more messy if MVC structure is consciously respected. It the opposite, maintainability will be increased as everything will be at the right place and correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your comment I will try more but I think although keeping html on controller or in view it is the same think(fast and slow). But if keep on Controller it may better for create shotcode which easy for echo it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Guidelines:**
**1)** Models are only for querying DB, getting results and that's it.
**2)** HTML tags shouldn't be in Controllers (not a good practice).
**3)** And answering to your question, it won't make any difference (faster or slower) in keeping the HTML tags in Controllers but you'll endup messing with your code.
**4)** Also why we use **MVC architecture** to keep our HTML (views), DB queries (models) separate. And whats your approach is not at all MVC oriented.

Here's a better approach,

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Xyz extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('xyz_model');
    }

    public function abc()
    {
        $data['menu'] = $this->xyz_model->get_menus();
        $this->load->view('xyz',$data);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
class Xyz_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);
    }

    public function get_menus
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('menus');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<html>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>

        <?php foreach($menu as $m) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $m->name; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that it.
But I used it everyday now and I have also separated it by file.php example
nav.php, slide.php .cat.php midl.php, header.php, footer.php, and than I will load it into my layout.php. I don't know another technique is better than this one. Do you have any new

Comment: No there's no better technique than this. This is simple and let your codebase cleaner.

Comment: OK, I will keep using this structures